# BackgroundWorker Return A Value?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The following code adds the numbers from 1 to 100 and returns the sum.  What I'm trying to do is run the calculations in a backgroundworker and return a value.  The problem with this is that returnValue is returned before DoWork completes.  How can I have it wait for my background worker to complete before returning a value? (I can't seem to put the return in my DoWork...)

```
double returnValue = 0;

var b = new BackgroundWorker();
b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            returnValue += (i+1);
        }
    }
);

b.RunWorkerAsync();
return returnValue;
```

Addendum: **Would it be better to send a message pump on the same thread instead of running this on a background worker?**

Also, this is just example code, my actual code takes more than a minute to complete.

Comment: Almost the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939635/how-to-make-backgroundworker-return-an-object

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182782/c-return-value-from-function-invoked-in-thread/5201814#5201814

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't make sense; you're trying to execute code on the `BackgroundWorker`, but you also want to block the calling method from returning until the `BackgroundWorker` is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event. That event contains the return value of the background operation.

Of course, that value would be returned from inside the `DoWorkEventHandler`, like so:

```
b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        double returnValue = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            returnValue += (i+1);
        }
        e.Result = returnValue;
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes this works well. I also like that the return value can be an object or struct.

Comment: not worked.error DoWorkEventHandler returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object

Comment: @BeeLabeille seems I wrote the "return" wrong, although after so many years I have no idea what I was thinking at the time. Anyway, setting `e.Result` is correct.

Comment: @Jon Yes, you are right. After a bit of digging around yesterday I eventually realised that what I needed to use was the Result property, hence my suggested answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a question here, but what I think you are looking for is the event called `RunWorkerCompleted`.  That gets raised when the `DoWork` delegate completes.  If this is not what you are looking for, I think you need to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

i have postet a sample: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213609/communicating-with-another-thread/5213638#5213638)
maybe it can help you :-)

> Also, this is just example code, my actual code takes more than a minute to complete.

this can be the effect of the async start. you can tell the backgroundworker when to start or just say start. if you don´t explicit say that he should start NOW he starts when c# thinks it is a good time to start :-)

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you were not able to use the accepted answer because DoWorkEventHandler returns void, the code below might help.

```
double returnValue = 0;
var b = new BackgroundWorker();
b.DoWork += PerformJob;
b.RunWorkerCompleted += JobDone;

private void PerformJob(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // Pre-Processing: for-loop to increment returnValue
    /*
    ** DoWorkEventArgs has a 'Result' object with the following description
    ** Summary: Gets or sets a value that represents the result of an asynchronous operation.
    ** Returns: An System.Object representing the result of an asynchronous operation.
    */
    args.Result = returnValue;
}

private void JobDone(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    //RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs also has a 'Result' object like DoWorkEventArgs
    double updatedReturnValue = (double)args.Result;

    // Post-processing: e.g. use updatedReturnValue to update a text block, show a message box etc.
}
```

Comment: Note that the accepted answer has now been edited to reflect the use of the 'Result' property instead of the 'return' statement

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to do a synchronous operation with BackgroundWorker which it **BAD**. But if you must, you could use the IsBusy flag.

```
double returnValue = 0;

var b = new BackgroundWorker();
b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            returnValue += (i+1);
        }
    }
);

b.RunWorkerAsync();
while(b.IsBusy){
  Application.DoEvents();
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: This kinda defeats the purpose of the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Bryan exactly. but if he has to wait for the BackgroundWorker to finish then why use BackgroundWorker ?

Comment: Would a message pump be better?

Comment: @sooprise like `Application.DoEvents();` ? sure

Comment: Calling Application.DoEvents is almost always a bad idea. msdn tries to make this clear but does not, imho, put sufficient emphasis on how bad an idea it is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: @adam The OP's situation is not traditional. Why create a BgWorker to add items and wait for the result when you can just have the for loop just in the method and return value. I know it's bad practice and I have indicated that in my answer. I'm assuming the OP is just experimenting with BackgroundWorker and I'm trying to answer the OP without trying to make suggestions of good practices.

Comment: @adam here's a better article on DoEvents() http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html